# vue-apollo mutation trigger unexpected subscription

Tags: apollo, vue-apollo

I have a smart query in my entry component. It will show items when page loads.

```
apollo: {
    feed: {
      query: FEED_QUERY,
      result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
        console.log("Feed success!");
        this.feedItems(data.feed); // sync vuex state
      },
      error(error) {
        console.error("Feed error!", error);
      },
      watchLoading(isLoading, countModifier) {

      }
    }
}
```

And I add a standard subscription in `created` hook, which will refresh items once observing changes.

```
  created: function() {
    const _this = this;
    const observer = this.$apollo.subscribe({
      query: ITEM_SUBSCRIPTION
    });
    observer.subscribe({
      next(data) {
        _this.$apollo.queries.feed.refetch();
      },
      error(error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  },
```

When I do any mutation like this,

```
this.$apollo
    .mutate({
      mutation: ITEM_DELETE_MUTATION,
      variables: {
        id
      }
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log("Delete item success!");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Delete item fail!");
    });
```

I expect console to log out:

```
Delete item success!
Observe changes!
Feed success!
```

but actually it prints

```
Feed success!    <-------- unexpected
Delete item success!
Observe changes!
Feed success!
```

I don't know how was the first `Feed success!` message trigged. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `result` callback is called when a query is loading.

This comes handy when you are designing optimistic UI where you present a fake response from the server to a user and after you get an actual response you update it.

If you want to prevent it just do:

```
result({data, loading, networkStatus}) {
  if (loading) return
  console.log('Feed success!')
  this.feedItems(data.feed) // sync vuex state
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried with it but still the same. You are right in that the first query does not call the server and it just returns last results.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Your FEED_QUERY query will be executed right after your component is created and each time ITEM_SUBSCRIPTION subscription changes.